# Rotate image using seekBar in android

Tags: android

I have following code to rotate an image, but when i drag the seekBar it creates a new bitmap on older image (it should rotate the older image instead of creating new one) , can some one help me in sorting this thing out.?
i have visited my older questions , but no one solved this for me

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

```
ImageView iv_image;
SeekBar seekbar;
Bitmap source;
float angle = 0;
Button buttonClick;
Bitmap rotatedImage;
static Matrix matrix;
Matrix m1 ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
    buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);
    buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            angle += 90;

            iv_image.buildDrawingCache();
            source = iv_image.getDrawingCache();
            rotatedImage = rotateImage(source, angle);
            iv_image.setImageBitmap(rotatedImage);
        }
    });
}

void init() {
    iv_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
    seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
   // seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener((OnSeekBarChangeListener) this);

}

public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    angle = progress;
    iv_image.buildDrawingCache();
    source = iv_image.getDrawingCache();
    rotatedImage = rotateImage(source, angle);
    iv_image.setImageMatrix(null);
    iv_image.setImageBitmap(rotatedImage);
}

public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap sourceImage, float angle) {
    matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceImage, 0, 0, sourceImage.getWidth(),
            sourceImage.getHeight(), matrix, true);

}
```

Comment: I don't think you posted your code... =P

Comment: Why would you replace the entire bitmap when you can just update the image matrix with the new rotation angle? That would be far more efficient!

Comment: give some code please

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
public static void rotateImage(float angle) {
    matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    imageView.invalidate();
}
```

Here's your interface implementation:

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    angle = progress;
    rotateImage(angle);
}
```

This way you would rotate the Bitmap inside the ImageView which is a lot more efficient.

You could even reuse the Matrix object by making it a private member and calling *imageView.invalidate()* after rotation in order to optimize your code.

Comment: this is not rotating the image

Comment: Maybe you have to call imageView.invalidate(); to make it work. I've updated the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void rotateImage(float angle) {
    matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    imageView.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this answer solves the problem and how it improves on the existing answer?

Comment: you should set the imageview scale type Matrix


imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);